# How to make pseudo-element follow text across line break?

Tags: css, opacity, line-breaks, pseudo-element

I've created CSS for anchor text that transitions a `background-color` and a `border-bottom` using `opacity`. (This is done to meet the Chrome Lighthouse auditor's spec on avoiding transitions except on compositor-only effects.)

The CSS puts the transitioned items on a `::before` pseudo-element built on the anchor. *Notice that the pseudo-element is absolutely positioned, which is a requirement of the technique as currently constructed.* It works except when the anchor text follows a line break. A working, illustrated example is provided on [this CodePen](https://codepen.io/bmt-systems-codepen/full/mdryzLL).

The CSS and HTML are also provided here:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  margin: 1em;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

header,
article {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 1em;
  width: 100%;
}

p {
  padding-bottom: 1em;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 1em;
}

a {
  background-color: transparent;
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  color: blue;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
}

a::before {
  background-color: lightgray;
  border-bottom-color: blue;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  content: '';
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 500ms ease;
  position: absolute;
  top: -5px;
  left: 0;
  bottom: -5px;
  right: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

a:hover::before {
  opacity: 1;
}

a::after {
  --icon-width: 24px;
  color: blue;
  content: '';
  background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHdpZHRoPSIyNCIgaGVpZ2h0PSIyNCIgdmlld0JveD0iMCAwIDI0IDI0IiBmaWxsPSJub25lIiBzdHJva2U9ImJsdWUiIHN0cm9rZS13aWR0aD0iMiIgc3Ryb2tlLWxpbmVjYXA9InJvdW5kIiBzdHJva2UtbGluZWpvaW49InJvdW5kIiBjbGFzcz0iZmVhdGhlciBmZWF0aGVyLWV4dGVybmFsLWxpbmsiPjxwYXRoIGQ9Ik0xOCAxM3Y2YTIgMiAwIDAgMS0yIDJINWEyIDIgMCAwIDEtMi0yVjhhMiAyIDAgMCAxIDItMmg2Ij48L3BhdGg+PHBvbHlsaW5lIHBvaW50cz0iMTUgMyAyMSAzIDIxIDkiPjwvcG9seWxpbmU+PGxpbmUgeDE9IjEwIiB5MT0iMTQiIHgyPSIyMSIgeTI9IjMiPjwvbGluZT48L3N2Zz4=);
  margin-left: 0.2em;
  padding-left: var(--icon-width);
  background-size: var(--icon-width) var(--icon-width);
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  z-index: 999;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <ul>
      <li><a href=#>Anchor 1</a></li>
      <li><a href=#>Anchor 2</a></li>
      <li><a href=#>Anchor 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </header>
  <article>
    <h1>Composited transitions on border-bottom and background-color</h1>
    <p>Avoid non-composited transitions! <code>opacity</code> and <code>transform</code> transitions are preferred by the Lighthouse auditor.</p>
    <p>See: <a href=https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/rendering/stick-to-compositor-only-properties-and-manage-layer-count/ target=_blank rel="noreferrer noopener">Stick to Compositor-Only Properties and Manage Layer Count</a> by
      Paul Lewis of Google.</p>
    <p>Hover over the links to see the <code>border-bottom</code> and <code>background-color</code> fade in to cover the link text fully. This method works so long as the anchor text does not wrap across lines.</p>
    <p><strong><em>Resize the window until the long link text on the line above this one wraps to a second line. At that point, the technique fails.</em></strong></p>
    <p>Can you see a solution for the CSS?</p>
  </article>
</body>
```

How would I edit the CSS so that the `::before` element follows the line break of the anchor text?

Comment: you are obliged to consider background properties here. Absolute element won't do the job with inline elements

Comment: @temani-afif The challenge is to reproduce the transition using only opacity or transform, which are the two kinds of transition that are allowed by the Lighthouse auditor now. The closest I could come is in the provided code, which works except in the case of line breaks. Can you see a way to reproduce the same on-off transition only using opacity or transform?

Comment: unless you build something very *hacky*, you cannot do it using only transform and opacity